# Test is not finding variable used within the same test

Tags: robotframework

I divided the organization of my tests into three steps:

**CreateProfessionalTest.robot**: where test scenarios are located

**CreateProfessionalPage.robot**: where are page variables and elements

**CreateProfessionalSteps.robot**: where are the test execution keywords

Inside **CreateProfessionalSteps.robot**, in certain part of the test, I used FakerLibrary to create a name and put the option Set Global Variable, because I will need to use this same fake name in another part of the same test.

```
${FAKE_PROFESSIONAL_NAME}           FakerLibrary.name male
Set Global Variable                 ${FAKE_PROFESSIONAL_NAME}
Log                                 ${FAKE_PROFESSIONAL_NAME}
Input Text                          ${PROFESSIONAL_NAME_FIELD}           ${FAKE_PROFESSIONAL_NAME}
```

Then, already on **CreateProfessionalPage.robot**, create a variable with an Xpath containing the variable ${FAKE_PROFESSIONAL_NAME} inside, since I want to look for the specific element for this fake name.

```
${PROFESSIONAL_STATUS_CARD}     xpath=//p[text()='${FAKE_PROFESSIONAL_NAME}']/following::div/following::div/following::div[@class='mp-card--actions']
```

Finally, inside **CreateProfessionalSteps.robot**, I want to get the text inside this element to compare and see if it's correct.

```
${PROFESSIONAL_STATUS}    Get Text       ${PROFESSIONAL_STATUS_CARD}
```

But when I run the test, it returns the following error message:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'C:\Professionals\CreateProfessionalPage.robot' on line 132: Setting variable '${PROFESSIONAL_STATUS_CARD}' failed: Variable '${FAKE_PROFESSIONAL_NAME}' not found.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you please try to create a small [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you get this error because you are trying to use dynamic variable value for a locator variable `${PROFESSIONAL_STATUS_CARD}`, which is defined in variables table, but variable `${FAKE_PROFESSIONAL_NAME}` doesn't exist in this context, as its defined in a keyword and not in a variables table section.